# tarmk-coldstandby.log keeps on increasing for AEM6.1

Tags: aem, jackrabbit-oak

I see the tarmk-coldstandby.log keeps on increasing as below log snippet.

```
08.04.2016 15:20:08.984 DEBUG [defaultEventExecutorGroup-5-1] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentTracker Added segment ddfdd5d1-c66d-4a15-bbe4-554a02698dda to tracker cache (1024 bytes)
08.04.2016 15:20:09.005 DEBUG [defaultEventExecutorGroup-5-1] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentId Loading segment 7a81e4a1-0164-41b3-bade-765ad98e3892
08.04.2016 15:20:09.005 DEBUG [defaultEventExecutorGroup-5-1] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentTracker Added segment 7a81e4a1-0164-41b3-bade-765ad98e3892 to tracker cache (1024 bytes)
08.04.2016 15:20:09.062 DEBUG [defaultEventExecutorGroup-5-1] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentId Loading segment 9ceb0986-cf88-44de-bc5d-cf3c1c564d17
08.04.2016 15:20:09.062 DEBUG [defaultEventExecutorGroup-5-1] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentTracker Added segment 9ceb0986-cf88-44de-bc5d-cf3c1c564d17 to tracker cache (1024 bytes)
08.04.2016 15:20:09.093 DEBUG [defaultEventExecutorGroup-5-1] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentId Loading segment 9499975f-f741-40fe-b93f-fddb3c744c3e
08.04.2016 15:20:09.093 DEBUG [defaultEventExecutorGroup-5-1] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentTracker Added segment 9499975f-f741-40fe-b93f-fddb3c744c3e to tracker cache (1024 bytes)
08.04.2016 15:20:09.112 DEBUG [defaultEventExecutorGroup-5-1] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentId Loading segment 15b7c96d-3d9c-4a9e-b52f-c3d3daa99cb0
08.04.2016 15:20:09.112 DEBUG [defaultEventExecutorGroup-5-1] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentTracker Added segment 15b7c96d-3d9c-4a9e-b52f-c3d3daa99cb0 to tracker cache (1024 bytes)
08.04.2016 15:20:09.143 DEBUG [defaultEventExecutorGroup-5-1] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentId Loading segment 1512b2f6-9c58-4804-bb5a-3dd6d1c17379
08.04.2016 15:20:09.143 DEBUG [defaultEventExecutorGroup-5-1] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentTracker Added segment 1512b2f6-9c58-4804-bb5a-3dd6d1c17379 to tracker cache (1024 bytes)
08.04.2016 15:20:09.172 DEBUG [defaultEventExecutorGroup-5-1] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentId Loading segment 8b336377-ba60-4268-bd7e-646deecf01cb
08.04.2016 15:20:09.172 DEBUG [defaultEventExecutorGroup-5-1] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentTracker Added segment 8b336377-ba60-4268-bd7e-646deecf01cb to tracker cache (1024 bytes)
```

Could someone please help us to understand this log and to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

Primary and Standby instances sync segments from Primary to Standby instance, the logging entries are related to that.

You can change the logging level for `tarmk-coldstandby.log` in the OSGi console or if you have created [Custom Sling OSGi config](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/deploy/configuring/monitoring-and-maintaining.html#Create%20a%20Custom%20Log%20File), it can be changed in the Sling OSGi config also.